# How to change the newline position

Tags: sed, files, string, search, special-characters

I have a file that contains string in each line. I used this file as an input in a program that reads them automatically. The program seem to not be able to read the strings correctly. I tried to fiure out what is different than usual. The only thing I found is that the file (I take it as-is from a source) adds the newline character at the beginning of the new line, and not at the end of the previous line as I used to see and as the program could successfully read previous files.

So if I use `cat -E file.txt` to see the newline character I see the file contains string like this:

```
string1
$string2
$string3
$string4
```

Note that the `$` is the newline character. 
As a troubleshooting step, I want to change the newline position to be:

```
string1$
string2$
string3$
string4$
```

How to do this?

Comment: Is the file a DOS text file with `\r\n` newlines?

Comment: It is retrieved from the Ineternet and saved it locally. I used it as an input to my program. As I said, it contains a list of strings. Originally it was a .csv file and I converted the extension to .txt but I used to change similar files (from other web sources) without issues.

Comment: @Kusalananda Can you tell me how to check to answer your question? All what I see with `cat -E` is what I put in the OP.

Comment: Use `dos2unix filename` to change the file's newlines from DOS to Unix.  This is very likely your issue. I have tested it to verify that `cat -E` produce this kind of output for DOS text files.

Comment: @user9371654 Use the `file` command, if tell you if it's plain ASCII or ASCII with DOS line endings.

Comment: Incidentally, it is the newline character that determines where the line ends, so you cannot have newline characters not at a line end.

Comment: @xenoid It's a side effect of the carriage return displacing the `$` in the output from `cat -E`.

Comment: This is the output of the `file` command: `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: @user9371654 Yep, `CRLF` is "carriage return followed by line feed", i.e. a DOS text file.